# What should I consider this circuit?

Tags: communication

It's an antenna with LC rasonant circuit. What should I consider this circuit? Is it an AC source, inductor and capacitor all parallel with each other or Is it an AC source, inductor and capacitor all in series with each other?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean how should you **model** the circuit?  It depends on the physical structure of the antenna, and since it's drawn as a single-ended probe, on the physical structure of the ground, as well.

Comment: Alex, are you looking for a "phrase?" If so and if you want to include the antenna as well as the tank circuit then perhaps you could consider the unit as an *RF source transducer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They’re all in parallel in the sense that one end of each component is connected to ground and the other ends are all connected together, if you look at the antenna as an AC source relative to ground.  Whether that’s an appropriate assumption depends on what your intentions are; the antenna has a much higher source impedance than you would normally expect for an AC supply.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the AC source the antenna and ground, then all are in parallel. When modelling, the AC source should have a series resistor as the impedance of the L and C will change with frequency.